# How can i use Thesaurus libraries in solr

Tags: solr, thesaurus

I need to implement synonym search using solr. For this i need to import thesaurus libraries in solr. I tried searching for importing thesaurus libraries in solr but no luck.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question in its current form - what libraries? Do they have an existing module for Solr? Are you planning to write your own? Is there a reason why you can't export a format to use the regular synonym file? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordnet library.

steps
1) Install wordnet on server.
2) Call wordnet library with search keyword.
3) Then pass all keywords to solr.